# Locomotive wagon does not display data in local development site

Tags: locomotivecms, wagon

I have an existing locomotive site that I am setting up for development on my machine. The engine is running locally and I am using the wagon gem to edit the theme files.

The engine seems to be fine, although a little slow.
What I am having trouble with is the wagon side of things.

I have set up the deploy.yml to point to my local engine and run `wagon pull development` this started fine but timed out before it could pull everything. So instead I ran `wagon pull staging` to pull from the existing staging server and this ran fine.

**When I run `wagon serve` I get the template files showing correctly but none of the content from the data yaml files is shown.**

Am I missing something or is it an issue created by first pulling from development then staging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out someone else working on the project had extended liquid inside the engine to add a couple of extra things. These things were needed to show the content, but as the wagon gem didn't contain these extensions it couldn't use them to show the content.

The fix was to just use wagon to push to a local engine to view the changes.